# How to exclude SQL variable in output

Tags: sql

I have a complex SQL query where I have a few cases that use END AS variableName. I then use variableName to do some logic and then create a new variable which I want in the output result. However when I run the query, all the END AS variableNames that I have used are also outputted in the results.

Is there a way that I can exclude these variables as I only want the final variable that uses these variableNames.

Thanks

EDIT, here is a query explaining my problem

SELECT  DISTINCT
mt.src_id AS “SRC_ID”,

```
CASE
    WHEN mt.cd = ‘TAN’ THEN
    (
        (
    SELECT  SUM(src_amt)
        FROM    source_table st
        WHERE   mt.id = st.id
            AND  st._cd = ‘TAN’
            AND  st.amt_cd = ‘ABL’)
    )
END AS src_amt

FROM  MAIN_TABLE mt
WHERE  
mf.dt >= 2021-12-12   
AND SRC_AMT > 10
```

I need SRC_AMT to be used as some sort of logic but when I run the query, it prints out in the output as it's own column. I want to ignore this variable

Comment: The answer is yes, but with no details of your actual query or the RDBMS you're using, unable to say more.

Comment: Please provide your query

Comment: Simplify as possible. [mcve]

Comment: You're referring to *aliases*, not *variables*

Comment: You could wrap your query in an outer-select or use an *exists* criteria, or aggregate with *having*

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the whole thing into a new select-statement:

`select SRC_ID from ( <entire previous query here> )`